# Parse xml in jquery - ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

**This code works.**

```
    var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );

    console.log($title.text()); // RSS Title
```

**This does not:**

```
        success: function( xml ) {

        // Extract relevant data from XML
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $title = $xml.find( "Country" );

        console.log($title.text());

        }
```

**My xml form:**

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'GetCitiesByCountryResult' => string '<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Fuerteventura / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Hierro / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>La Palma / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Las Palmas De Gran Canaria / Gando</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country>
    <City>Lanzarote / Aeropuerto</City>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Country>Spain</Country'... (length=4383)
```

**php:**

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST[ 'facultyname' ] ) ) {
    //Create the client object
    $soapclient = new SoapClient( 'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL' );

    //Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in the associative array.
    $params = array( 'CountryName' => $_POST[ 'facultyname' ] );
    $response = $soapclient->GetCitiesByCountry( $params );

    var_dump( $response );
}
else {
    echo 'Some error on php receiving side.';
}

?>
```

My XML is returning object maybe that's why I can't getting my country names. I tried a lot but nothing getting work.
I am using a web service [Link](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetCitiesByCountry) as a demo test.

Comment: How are you encoding the object when you return it? Are you using JSON?

Comment: No i am not using jSon.I am just using the above code and getting the data from this `http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL`

Comment: Where is the `stdClass` object coming from?

Comment: i think from the globalweather web service. beacuse i am doing no encoding

Comment: You can't use `var_dump()` as a way of sending data to the client, it can't parse that into XML. Either echo the property containing the XML, or use `json_encode` to send the object, and `JSON.parse()` in JS to parse it, and then access the property you want.

Comment: The object is coming from the `SoapClient` class.

Comment: Ok i will try that in an hour and respond back.